# Why my ads do not show up on Google?

Tags: google-ads

My friend bid for "catalog carrefour". If I search for "catalog carrefour" on Google, I would expect some ads showing up on top.

It didn't. 
My ads doesn't show up. Even though Google AdWords say my ads rank 1.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of different reason's why this could be happening:

- You have reached your budget limit for that day
- You have incorrectly set the keywords
- You're not bidding high enough
- You're not advertising in that area

Try going to Tools - Ad Preview and Diagnosis and find out what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already checked your Ad to ensure it is configured correctly (target geographic region and times, daily budgets, keyword bids etc) then perhaps you should check the keywords have been specified inside square brackets `[]` to ensure [exact phrase matching](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2407781?hl=en-GB) rather than the default broad matching.

To give an example, for this Ad you might enter a series of keyword phrases such as:

- `[catalog carrefour]`,
- `[carrefour catalog]`,
- `[catalogue carrefour]`,
- `[carrefour catalogue]`,
- `[carrefour]`.

If after reading and understanding about the different [keyword matching options](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497836?hl=en-GB) available you wish to strategically use a mix of both matching options this is not a problem, but I would recommend a combination in this case rather than using only broad match keyword phrases.

**Edit:** The keyword phrase quality can also impact whether your ad gets shown. If the quality score for the keywords you're trying is low (below 6) then it might be you either need to make changes to your website so that those keywords are deemed more relevant by AdWords or you might need to change your keyword combination to something more specific.